# Rails email whitelist is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am using https://github.com/brightin/mail_whitelist gem

In my initializer I have the following code

```
require 'mail_whitelist'

if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.dev?
  whitelist = ['@mydomain.com']
  fallback = 'myemail@gmail.com'

  ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(MailWhitelist.new(whitelist, fallback))
end
```

The fallback works , but when I am trying to send an email to a whitelisted domain like myname@mydomain.com it doesn't go out, everything is send to fallback.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def delivering_email(mail)
    mail.to = mail.to.select { |recipient| whitelisted?(recipient) }
    mail.to = [fallback] unless mail.to.any?
  end
```

seems like u dont prove any emails to mailer so mail.to becomes fallback.
because whitelisted function is writtern right and your whitelist should compute true.